# think/ponder/ruminate/contemplate

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, usage

We can *think about future.*

But can we say some of these ways?:

- We should *ruminate about future*
- We should *ponder about future*
- We should *contemplate about future*

Do any some of them make a sense?

Or they are not usual?

Answer (score 1):

For a start, all these would need to be "about *the* future*. But "ponder" and "contemplate" take direct objects, and can't be used like this; you contemplate a thing, not about a thing. So:

> We should contemplate the future.